# Selecting rows from the same table using a reference

Tags: mysql

I am having a table named tblA.I am having the following set of values.

```
ID    REF     
---------
1     ASD    
2     null    
3     null    
4     null    
5     FGH     
6     null
```

Now I am trying to get the rows 1 to 4(i.e the starting row will be the one with value 'ASD' in ref column and last row will be the one previous to the row that has some values in REF column say 'FGH').

I tried with between keyword but I am not getting it right.Any way to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could use the rank method:

```
select * from(
SELECT @rank :=  IF(@prevVal<>ref or ref is null,@rank, @rank+1) AS rank, 
       id,ref,
@prevVal:=ref
FROM   scores
, 
       (SELECT @rank := 0,@prevVal:=null) r 
order by id) m
where m.rank=1
```

[SQL FIDDLE here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88757/7)

Comment: One more clarification sel..Here we need to specify rank value (i.e if set as 1, rows 1 to 4 will be displayed) but i may also need to fetch FGH and null value rows below that.I will pass the reference dynamically.Based on that the result sould be produced. I tried adding ref value while setting rank value but it's incorrect. pls help.

Comment: you could change to `where m.rank between 1 and 2`

Comment: I tried but the result is same as said above. The rows in the table given above are sample ones.I may have multiple references like the ones given in the above table.For e.g. if i get ASD as input it shoud fetch from ASD to the next not null row in ref column.So i cannot specify the rank value explicitly it should be dynamic based upon the ref sent in as input.

Comment: In order to retrieve the rows based on value ASD. Would have to join itself the table again to retrieve the value. Here is the fiddle [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88757/23

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, REF, 
    (CASE WHEN REF IS NOT NULL THEN @refs := @refs + 1 ELSE @refs END) AS counter
FROM (  SELECT ID, REF
        FROM tblA, (SELECT @refs := 0) AS vars
        WHERE ID >= 1
        ORDER BY ID ASC) AS h
HAVING counter = 1
```

This should work for you.